# Por qué se regresa a contar la varibale de react en use state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

Mi problema es que estoy haciendo una práctica en react, estoy usando useState y un setInterval para poder ver cómo es el funcionamiento del estado. Pero al momento de hacer que la variable del useState cambie para así poder mostrarlo en pantalla, se muestra un reconteo.

```
**import { useState } from "react";

function Estado() {
  const [intervalo, setIntervalo] = useState(0);

  setInterval(() => {
    setInt(int + 1)
  }, 400);

  return <h1>{intervalo}</h1>;
}

export default Estado;**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En react no puedes dejar el `setInterval` dentro del componente, ya que cuando se ejecute, estás renderizando de nuevo todo el componente y incluso el setInterval, es decir, reseteándolo.

Para usar `setInterval` dentro de un componente, Usalo dentro de un `useEffect` Y forza el rerender con un `clearInterval`, de esta forma

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Estado() {
  const [intervalo, setIntervalo] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
         setIntervalo(prevIntervalo => prevIntervalo + 1);
      }, 600);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [])

  return <h1>{intervalo}</h1>;
}
```